# Who is this silhouetted figure in the first OP?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

In the first OP for Tokyo Ravens, the figure pictured below appears for about two seconds, silhouetted the entire time.

[image: some mysterious shadowy entity]

Who is s/he? That profile (and specifically, that hairstyle - see this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvm1L.gif)) doesn't seem to fit any of the other characters in the show.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Atsune Hirata who turn out to be a spy for the Twin Horn Syndicate.

Comment: Hm, you think so? That doesn't quite look like Hirata's build or hairstyle to me. His hair is a lot pointier, for one.